# Sending live data to a client: Are websockets the best option (Vuex & Socket.io?

Tags: socket.io, vuex

I'm trying to set up a front end UI for the webApp I've been working on and have a clarification question before proceeding further.

Right now I have  multiple sensor units streaming data to the server that is saving it to a database and then set up a crude api, to be expanded on later, to interface with the server and DB.

Now, moving to the front end, I feel like I'm bashing my heading first trying to learn react and now vue. The first feature of the UI I'd like to have is to constantly see the sensor data displayed in a table on the browser.

Should I be calling this data from the server using the API http requests or have it sent using websockets?

After spending a few hours trying to get vue connected to the socket opened on the server I wanted to check if I'm just looking in the wrong direction to begin with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to create a websocket connections since your data is continuously changing. You are definitely on the right track.

Just create an `vuex action` that will `commit` your data to the store. It does't really matter which websocket tool you use. Most of them work quite the same. There will be most likely a callback function which gets triggered when new data has been sent to the front-end. This is where you would call your `vuex action` and pass through the data. If you can edit your question with some sample code, I can help you in more detail.

**Just to some it up**:

1) Open Websocket connection to backend service

2) Create action which would save the data to store via mutations

3) Specify websocket callback function to call action